# Google Maps API v3 not drawing map when map type set Hybrid

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Drawing this map with the mapTypeId set to hybrid, it draws the markers but not the  map.  If I set it to any other type, the map draws.

Also, if I hit F12 to bring up the developer tools, the map draws.

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Hybrid Map</title>
    <style>
      #map { height: 100%; }
      html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 42.31391, lng: -83.2032224};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatLng,
          mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
        });

        var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var markJson = [
        {Latitude: "42.34383937323032", Longitude: "-83.17619508650093", Accuracy: "24.0", Time: "09/08/2018 06:26:12"},
        {Latitude: "42.34386827380892", Longitude: "-83.17627864355015", Accuracy: "12.0", Time: "09/08/2018 06:26:14"},
        {Latitude: "42.343853008205535", Longitude: "-83.1763372997278", Accuracy: "4.0", Time: "09/08/2018 06:26:21"},
        {Latitude: "42.34387834632138", Longitude: "-83.1763972853329", Accuracy: "4.0", Time: "09/08/2018 06:26:47"},
        {Latitude: "42.343924132536046", Longitude: "-83.1763958907264", Accuracy: "6.0", Time: "09/08/2018 06:26:58"},
        {Latitude: "42.343914870976725", Longitude: "-83.17646834553283", Accuracy: "16.0", Time: "09/08/2018 06:27:10"},
        {Latitude: "42.34387223953695", Longitude: "-83.17649826835593", Accuracy: "16.0", Time: "09/08/2018 06:27:13"}
        ];

        markJson.forEach(function(item, index) {
            var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: newLatLng,
            map: map
            });
            markerBounds.extend(marker.position);
        });     

        google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function () {
            map.fitBounds(markerBounds);
    });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The posted [code works for me (fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/g7dpoza8/)

Comment: I actually fiddle'd it before I posted it and saw it working there too.  But it does not work in the browser.  Can you try in your browser of choice?

Comment: On a local file, works in IE11, exhibits the issue in Chrome 67, and Firefox 52.9.  Which browser are you using?

Comment: I see the issue in Chrome 68, Edge 38, Firefox 62.  Didn't try it in IE.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, when Google Maps executes the fitBounds, it is setting the zoom level to 22.  At this location in the world, Google Maps does not have the images at zoom level 22.  Initializing the map with maxZoom set to 21 sets the problem in this instance.

```
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        maxZoom: 21,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
    });
```

Google maps also provides a getMaxZoomAtLatLng function to find the max zoom level at a particular latitude & longitude.

Answer (score -1):

You do not have an API key added in your script tag:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API KEY]&callback=initMap"></script>
```

You can get one here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: My code uses a key.  When I shared the code, I pulled my key out.  I also tested the code I posted without a key, and it just throws a console error.